# web-based data synchronization via peer to peer

Tags: web, synchronization, distributed, p2p, peerjs

I want to build an app which allows me to add users and share some simple data (my and other contacts, including name, adresss, etc.) with them.

I've setup these requirements:

- should work on each device and os (computers, tablets, phones)
- decentralized; data is ideally neither send via a server nor stored on a server

  - using STUN/TURN is okay but port forwarding, etc. due to NAT is no option

I would like to avoid building real native apps and searched for some tools/libraries. I found https://peerjs.com/ which sounds promising.

The sync (and even establish the first connection by sharing the peer IDs) between two peers would work only when both are online. In order to do the connnection stuff in the background my idea was to use webworkers but for iOS even webworkers are paused if safari is not running in the foreground. I could live with that limitation but maybe there is something else what I didn't considered yet?

Maybe there is even a better library or tool there for this kind of task?

Comment: Note that with webrtc you still need a signalling server (PeerServer in peerjs) and if a peer connection expires or needs to be renegotiated then it won't work if such a server is not available or the peers are trying to use a different server, so connectivity still has a central point of failure, only the data is kept off the server.

Comment: I just found out (today) that it's also working without a signaling server (and even internet). Here is an explanation and a demo: https://mac-blog.org.ua/webrtc-one-to-one-without-signaling-server the data which needs to be exchanged could be exchanged via QR codes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what a signalling server does too. The issue is, to my knowledge, that those offers are only valid 1 time since they contain a random session ID. So every time webrtc needs to renegotiate you'd have to repeat that dance. It's not like a DHT where a node can just remember a public key hash and look it up later whenever it needs.